# How to fix Sankey Diagram error "to many dimensions" using networkD3 in R?

Tags: r, sankey-diagram, networkd3

I am trying to create a Sankey Diagram using networkD3 on RStudio.

I downloaded my data as a JSON file which I then imported into the studio and appears as this in the file on my desktop:

```
 {"nodes":[
 {"name":"Hypertension"},
 {"name":"Diabetes"},
 {"name":"smoking"},
 {"name":"Hypercholesterolemia"},
 {"name":"Obesity"},

 {"name":"Hypertension"},
 {"name":"Diabetes"},
 {"name":"smoking"},
 {"name":"Hypercholesterolemia"},
 {"name":"Obesity"},

 {"name":"Hypertension"},
 {"name":"Diabetes"},
 {"name":"smoking"},
 {"name":"Hypercholesterolemia"},
 {"name":"Obesity"},

 {"name":"Hypertension"},
 {"name":"Diabetes"},
 {"name":"smoking"},
 {"name":"Hypercholesterolemia"},
 {"name":"Obesity"},

 {"name":"Hypertension"},
 {"name":"Diabetes"},
 {"name":"smoking"},
 {"name":"Hypercholesterolemia"},
 {"name":"Obesity"}
 ]}


 {"links":[
 {"source":0,"target":5,"value":0.654},
 {"source":5,"target":10,"value":0.633},
 {"source":10,"target":15,"value":0.602},
 {"source":15,"target":20,"value":0.561},

 {"source":1,"target":6,"value":0.359},
 {"source":6,"target":11,"value":0.316},
 {"source":11,"target":16,"value":0.26},
 {"source":16,"target":21,"value":0.187},

 {"source":2,"target":7,"value":0.171},
 {"source":7,"target":12,"value":0.156},
 {"source":12,"target":17,"value":0.142},
 {"source":17,"target":22,"value":0.128},

 {"source":3,"target":8,"value":0.171},
 {"source":8,"target":13,"value":0.156},
 {"source":13,"target":18,"value":0.142},
 {"source":18,"target":23,"value":0.128},

 {"source":4,"target":9,"value":0.171},
 {"source":9,"target":14,"value":0.156},
 {"source":14,"target":19,"value":0.142},
 {"source":19,"target":24,"value":0.128}
 ]}
```

When imported to Rstudio the beginning looks different and I am not sure if that is part of the problem (photo attached)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zupoH.png)

With the code I based on SankeyDiagram code found on this forum and others i did:

```
install.packages('curl')
 install.packages("networkD3")
 library(networkD3)
 Energy<- read.csv2("~/Desktop/Energy.json", sep="")
```

## When I uploaded my data

Next is when I ran into some issues
Online the next steps would be

```
head(Energy$nodes) 
head(Energy$links)
```

Neither works and instead R urges me to do

```
head(Energy$X..nodes...)
```

which works but again not when i try links.

On top of that my final code should look something like this if the internet is correct:

```
networkD3::sankeyNetwork(Links = energy$X..links.., Nodes = Energy$X..nodes..., Source ="source", Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "Name", units = "TWh", fontSize = 12, nodeWidth = 30)
```

however I get the following error:

```
 Error in `[.default`(Links, , Source) : incorrect number of dimensions
```

I would appreciate any help! I also attached a picture of the Sankey Diagram I am trying to mimic![2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMokG.jpg)

Comment: CSV is not the same as JSON. Look into the `jsonlite` package for reading in your data.

Comment: I am so new to code, so I am very confused by that. How does that work, and how do I specifically fix that?

Comment: It’s like trying to play a CD in a cassette player.

Comment: so how do i fix that? I dont know how to use jsonlite i just need some direction

Comment: `jsonlite` has proper documentation that will better and more completely explain how to use it than I have time to do here.